# Sidebar buttons navigation

Tags: navigation

I'm building a new website for my own. I'm a student but in my spare time I try to earn a bit by being webdeveloper.

However from now on I want to focus a lot more on user experience, maximum conversion,...

I had an idea to use a special kind of navigation bar.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5s9ayj1g/4/

But I have the following questions regarding that:

1. Is this less/equally/more user-friendly than a standard navigation menu?
2. Will those images be more attracting to hover or click than standard text navigation?
3. Will this finally result in more leads (users browsing the whole website)?

And any other remarks on this?

Comment: This is quite a broad question and relies mainly on opinion and, while you will no doubt receive answers, you will need to test any innovation or deviation from expected patterns with your particular user base to understand fully how they will react to it and how it might affect the business associated with this product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's less user-friendly than a standard navigation menu, simply because of its location and that the user needs to hover over the icons to read whats behind them.
   People scan websites in an F-shaped pattern, which means the top
   left and right area of your website is the location which makes
   users look for the navigation area.
2. No, but users have to hover to know which text is behind those icons, which is bad UX. Try to avoid displaying icons only, combine icons + text whenever its possible.
3. I doubt it, most users will not even recognize that as a navigation, since in that area of a website usually things like support and/or social media related stuff is located.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll keep the standard top-navigation for desktop, and use an off-canvas navigation for mobile. The standard navigation will contain: Home, About us, Why choose us, contact, and blog; I'll use the special sidebar-button-navigation for Facebook, LinkedIn, and also contact and blog again; Does that seems good?

Comment: Yeah i think the sidebar will work well for social media related stuff.